# Configuring Time Capsule to distribute ISP given DHCP address

Tags: time-capsule

I am using tikona broadband internet and they usually have a 5 IP address restriction. I managed to by pass that by using a linksys router WRT120N . I setup the router to distribute IP addresses as 192.168.1.2-20.

However, when i am connecting my new time capsule, it seems to distribute IPs from DHCP as 10.x.x.2 onwards only.

How do i set up the time capsule so that it takes 10.x.x.x a its IP from DHCP and distributes over the network IPs as 192.168.1.X onwards?

That is also needed so that i will not have to login on each individual device with the ISP username and password on their website.

Comment: Greetings from Tikona. In order to assist you, we would require your contact or Tikona User ID details. We have assigned a reference number # TIKFB1815 to your case. Request you to write to us on tikonacare@tikona.in. with your details and mention the reference number in the subject line. Regards,
Tikona Care

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the router should be doing NAT, so your ISP won't see the local addresses at all.

To change the address range… source [AirPort Utility 6.x: Set DHCP options for your base station or your AirPort Time Capsule](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5140)

> If you’ve set up your base station or your AirPort Time Capsule to use Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) to provide IP addresses to computers and devices on your wireless network, you can choose the range of IP addresses a device uses, determine the amount of time a computer will have a valid IP address, enter a welcome message, and reserve specific IP addresses to assign to specific computers that join your network.
>
> 1. Open AirPort Utility, located in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder. Select the device you want to set up, then click Edit. Enter the password if necessary.
> 2. Click Network, and then choose either DHCP and NAT or DHCP Only from the Router Mode pop-up menu, depending on how you want to use DHCP.
> 3. Choose a range of IP addresses from the DHCP Range pop-up menu. Choose 10.0, 172.16, or 192.168, and then enter a beginning and ending address in the beginning and ending fields, depending on which addresses you want the device to provide.
>      If you set up a guest network, you can choose the address range for the guest network as well.
> 4. Enter a number in the DHCP Lease field, and then choose minutes, hours, or days from the pop-up menu.
> 5. To provide specific IP addresses to specific computers on your wireless network, click Add (+) below the DHCP Reservations list, and then follow the onscreen instructions to name the reservation. Reserve the address by MAC address or DHCP client ID. If you choose MAC address, click Continue and enter the MAC address and specific IP address.

It would be unwise to have the actual ranges overlapping. Set one to e.g. 1.92.168.1.2-10 & the other to .11-20

& don't have 2 devices both trying to do NAT, leave that to the main router.
Also, make sure the main router is only handing out addresses for wired devices & the TC for wireless, or they'll fight.

Comment: Wouldn't the simpler solution be to set the TC into Bridge Mode and let the Linksys router handle DHCP allocations?

Comment: probably. It was a bit of an XY question, but I thought I'd answer it as it stood.